# How to use UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning with UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, xamarin.ios

How can I get custom transitions (iOS7) when pushing a view controller onto `UINavigationController`? I tried setting the `TransitioningDelegate` both in the `UINavigationController` and also on the controller I'm pushing
The methods never get called.

All examples I find use custom transitions when presenting modally.

Comment: Please mark an answer as correct in response to your question

Answer (score 24, accepted):

@rounak has the right idea, but sometimes it helps to have code ready without having to download from github.

Here are the steps that I took:

1. Make your FromViewController.m conform to `UINavigationControllerDelegate`.  Other sample code out there tells you to conform to `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`, but that's only if you're *presenting* the ToViewController.

   @interface ViewController : UIViewController
2. Return your custom transition animator object in the delegate callback method in FromViewController:

   ```
   - (id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
                                  animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation
                                               fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC
                                                 toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC {
       TransitionAnimator *animator = [TransitionAnimator new];
       animator.presenting = (operation == UINavigationControllerOperationPush);
       return animator;
   }
   ```
3. Create your custom animator class and paste these sample methods:

   ```
   - (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
       return 0.5f;
       }

   - (void)animateTransition:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext     {
   // Grab the from and to view controllers from the context
   UIViewController *fromViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
   UIViewController *toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

   // Set our ending frame. We'll modify this later if we have to
   CGRect endFrame = CGRectMake(80, 280, 160, 100);

   if (self.presenting) {
       fromViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

       [transitionContext.containerView addSubview:fromViewController.view];
       [transitionContext.containerView addSubview:toViewController.view];

       CGRect startFrame = endFrame;
       startFrame.origin.x += 320;

       toViewController.view.frame = startFrame;

       [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] animations:^{
           fromViewController.view.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeDimmed;
           toViewController.view.frame = endFrame;
       } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
           [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
       }];
   }
   else {
       toViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

       [transitionContext.containerView addSubview:toViewController.view];
       [transitionContext.containerView addSubview:fromViewController.view];

       endFrame.origin.x += 320;

       [UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] animations:^{
           toViewController.view.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeAutomatic;
           fromViewController.view.frame = endFrame;
       } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
           [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
       }];
   }
   }
   ```

Essentially, the animator is the object doing the heavy lifting.  Of course, you can make your UINavigationControllerDelegate be a separate object, but that depends on how your architect your app.

Comment: I'm guessing `TransitionAnimator` is the UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning class. And I'm guessing he added the property `presenting` to it.

Answer (score 4):

objc.io's post on view controller transitions are specifically for pushing and popping view controllers. http://objc.io/issue-5/view-controller-transitions.html

I've done this animation (https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Tc7a.gif) solely based on the objc.io post.

In short you have to have a class(es) implementing `UINavigationControllerDelegate`, and `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` with the required methods for returning the correct animator, and performing the animations.

Comment: Can you share the animator code, I'm working on similar thing as shown in the image.

Comment: I've give CGAffineTransform(translationX: 1.02, y: 1.02) during push and during pop (0.01,0.01) seems to be working fine, would like to know what's your value too :)

Answer (score 2):

You can look at my demo project which demonstrates using custom transitions in `UINavigationController`. Look at https://github.com/Vaberer/BlurTransition.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Just realised this might not answer your question. But it is an alternative.

If you're using a storyboard you can do a custom transition by creating a custom segue.
In the attributes inspector change the segue class name to your custom transition class e.g. `MySegue`. Then create the `MySegue` class and implement the `-(void)perform` method to perform your transition.

```
- (void) perform{
      UIViewController *source = self.sourceViewController;
      UIViewController *destination = self.destinationViewController;
      [UIView transitionFromView:source.view
                          toView:destination.view
                        duration:0.50f
                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop
                      completion:nil];
}
```